# Firebase Security Rule for REST request

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am authenticating to firebase from IOS swift app using custom token generated from my server.The write request which involves searching particular value and then writing to different path and finally send push notification, those write requests i want to do it from the server. 
From the server i am able to write to firebase using REST API request using firebase secret. Now the current rule which i have set is 
`".write" : true`
which is not advised. Hence is there any way i can send the current authenticated token from swift app to my server or any other suggested way to achieve this?

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/user-auth

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the link has Java api client request.
Is there any way i could get my own authenticated token from firebase using swift. 
Something similar to what Fabric Digits does 
`Digits.sharedInstance().session()?.authToken`